# Display all record from data extension using AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i have created a data extension names as recordsDe. it have some record in it check picture and i want to display its all data my in cloud page.

like
Record A1    |   Record B1

Record A2    |   Record B2

Record A3    |   Record B3

Record A4    |   Record B4

I have written a code like this

```
%%[

var @FieldA, @FieldB, @row, @rows, @rowCount, @i

set @rows = LookupRows("recordsDe"," ")/* What should i update here */

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

set @row = row(@rows, @i) 
set @FieldA = field(@row,"FieldA")
set @FieldB = field(@row,"FieldB")

]%%

    %%=v(@FieldA)=%% | %%=v(@FieldB)=%%

%%[ 

next @i 

endif

]%%
```

i don't have 3rd field in DE because i don't want to display FieldA and FieldB records by matching using 3rd field. So anyone please help me how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a 3rd column, which always has the same value, e.g. "1". Let's call this column: *return*. However possible, I will not recommend this, as you don't have any control of how many rows will be parsed.

But if you choose this approach, your LookupRows will look like this:

```
LookupRows("recordsDe","return","1")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Ya we can do it by 3rd column but i just looking for something like select DataExtension and print all its record.

Comment: This is the only viable way of doing so in AmpScript. Remember to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Yeah, only other way to do it is via API or to a degree SSJS, which each have a 2500 record limit and are really bonkers solutions for something that can easily and much more efficiently be done with extra column in ampscript